# How is a shear pad of remote compliance device formed?

Tags: robotics

I am researching on mechanical design of remote compliance devices (RCC)†. In the RCC, manufactured by ATI, they use shear pads for lateral compliance. They mention that shear pads are elastomers bonded with metal shims. I couldn't find how it is being made. Are there layers of elastomers between wedging pieces (shims) or something else? How is adhesion being achieved?[image]